# Poetry install fails while installing packages

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I'm new to using poetry and I just tried installing packages using it but it keeps failing telling me file doesn't exist. I cloned my job site's gitlab repo and was using the already made lock file.

I also traced the path to the missing file and found it there so I'm really confuse on what's happening.

Any help with be appreciated.

Error message:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 65 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing typing-extensions (3.10.0.2)

  ValueError

  File \C:\Users\Sorin\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\56\d7\18\f93adbed1c649d8ddb36a356dc2e8715728ae757a0fb17dcb1ab69535c\typing_extensions-3.10.0.2-py3-none-any.whl does not exist

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\core\packages\file_dependency.py:40 in __init__
       36│             except FileNotFoundError:
       37│                 raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       38│
       39│         if not self._full_path.exists():
    →  40│             raise ValueError("File {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       41│
       42│         if self._full_path.is_dir():
       43│             raise ValueError("{} is a directory, expected a file".format(self._path))
```

Comment: This is a bug in poetry. See https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4479

Comment: @finswimmer Thank you. I'll look into it